# Construction of nonstandard finite difference schemes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Nonstandard finite difference schemes for the numerical integration of differential equations were proposed by Mickens [1]. Loosely speaking, they are derived from two rules:

1. Non-trivial representations of derivatives:
   $$
   \frac{dx}{dt} \rightarrow \frac{x_{k+1}-\psi(h)\,x_k}{\phi(h)}
   $$
   where the conventional discretization amounts to $\psi(h)=1,\phi(h)=h$.
2. *Non-local* substitution of nonlinear terms, e.g. $x_k^2 \rightarrow x_{k+1}\,x_k$ in the logistic equation
   $$
   \frac{dx}{dt}=x\,(1-x)
   $$
   produces the numerical scheme:
   $$
   x_{k+1}=\frac{1+h}{1+h\,x_k}x_k
   $$
   that reproduces the asymptotical stability of the equilibrium $x=1$ regardless the step size $h$.

So far, so good, but I feel that each such nonstandard method must be constructed *ad-hoc* for a particular ODE. Despite Micken's claim to the contrary ("examination of the results produced to date easily show this interpretation [...] to be false") I have still been unable to find a systematic methodology for construction of nonstandard methods.

Are there some constructive general rules that deliver methods or classes of methods, at least for particular cases (hamiltonian, energy-diminishing, etc.)?

[1] Mickens, Ronald E. Advances In The Applications Of Nonstandard Finite Difference Schemes, World Scientific Publishing Company, 2005.

Comment: Is the aim just to shift the negative terms on the right into the denominator to get a stabilized iteration? Your example only shows an order 1 modification, is the general approach extended to higher error order?

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann That is the point: I am not aware of any general approach

Comment: Yes, what I've seen was just a bunch of clever substitutions for isolated problems. No systematic approach. But I also do not have the books, I've seen only online articles based on them.